# How to a use the kernel trick on a XOR dataset to transform the dataset into a linearly separable dataset?

Tags: linear-transformations, transformation, data-structure

Let's say that I have the following data:
[image]

I want to find a transformation of this dataset that will make it linearly separable.
My thought was to bring the data around the origin and then multiply $X_1$ by $X_2$ to get the blue data on one side and the orange data on one side. the transformation would be given by
$$\phi(X_1,X_2) \rightarrow (X_1,X_2,(X_1-\mu1)(X_2-\mu2)).$$

However, I can't get to find the kernel of this transformation.
If I try to do the dot product between $\phi(X_1,X_2) \phi(Y_1,Y_2) $
I don't get a kernel.

What could be a good kernel to achieve such
transformation?

EDIT: I think a good kernel could be the RBF kernel but I am not sure how to apply it. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Sudix I don't see how $\mu_1=X_1/n$?

Comment: Quadratic polynomial kernel?